# Edit existing table style

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way to use an existing table style in Excel as the basis for a new table style? Say I've e.g. created a table looking like this, using one of the default tables in Excel:

[image]

However, I want the second row stripes to be light green instead of white / blank.

Is there any way to do this without recreating the formatting for the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can create and apply a new custom table style based on existing build-in table styles.

You can right-click an existing table style and select Duplicate.

[image: Duplicate an existing table style]

Modify table style as you want and click OK:

[image]

Give it a name and click OK to save it. Apply it to your tables.

Reference:[Format an Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370).